# how to install mysql connector to work with visual studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

i already install mysql 5 in my system and visual studio professional. and everybody work fine but how i can connect mysql database in server explore using installing connector

when i download connector for mysql i get the rar. the rar have some code but i not know how it work are anyone tell me what i do to use mysql in my server explorer

Comment: just download the .NET connector installer and install. http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.3.5.zip/from/ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.mysql.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go get Connector / net.  It's the dot Net connector software.  It comes in .msi form, not .rar form, and opens up Visual Studio to work with mySQL servers.  I know for sure that it works with VS2008 and VS2010.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/